# How to query a joined table (has_and_belongs_to_many) in a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have established a relation between project.rb and keyword.rb using has_and_belongs_to_many. 
I now want to query in my projects-controller all projects linked to a certain keyword. What is the easiest way to query the joined table keywords_projects?
Where is the connector from projects.rb to the joined table?

```
@projects = Project.find(:all, :conditions => [??])
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy way:

```
@projects = Keyword.find('keyword').projects
```

or:

@projects = Project.all(:conditions => {:keywords => {:name => 'keyword'}}, :include => :keywords)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems something's wrong in my Rails app then:

In both my models (here Folder and Role), I have habtm's defined (:roles, :folders). CRUD works, the folders_roles table exists so the DB is populated flawlessly. But when trying to query ...

```
@folders = Role.where("name = ?", "family").folders
```

... in my folder's controller, Rails barks about ...

```
undefined method `folders' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0xb6ecc12c>
```

(I simply want to load only those folders, that are associated with the role called "family".)